# open image instead of popup : leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am working with leaflet api.I can draw rectangles and polygons.I have bound the popup with every rectangle and polygon.When i click on drawn shape, popup opens(leaflet functionality).Popup contains some html(image).

As i am working on a demo application, i am wiling to try the fancebox plugin.
Means, when i click on drawn shape, instead of popup, i want to open up that image using fancybox.

Can i do that using simple method like using another function instead of .bindpopup.

**Working Script (image loaded using fance box when we click on popup)**

```
e.layer.bindPopup("<a class='fancybox' rel='group' href=''><img /></a>");
```

I can understand there must be some other javascript function to do it.
If there is some way to do it please let me know, as i am new to leaflet didn't have enough mental power to understand it yet but i hope i will....

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do `e.layer.on('click', function() { //do fancybox init, perhaps like $(body).append("<a class='fancybox' rel='group' href=''><img /></a>")})`
Although it makes a lot more performance sense to bind that event on the `L.FeatureGroup` holding all the shapes instead of one by one.

Comment: exactly what i been looking for, thanks for the help